# Pandas: How to remove rows from a dataframe based on a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe **customers** with some "bad" rows, the key in this dataframe is CustomerID. I know I should drop these rows. I have a list called **badcu** that says `[23770, 24572, 28773, ...]` each value corresponds to a different "bad" customer.

Then I have another dataframe, lets call it **sales**, so I want to drop all the records for the bad customers, the ones in the **badcu** list.

If I do the following

```
sales[sales.CustomerID.isin(badcu)]
```

I got a dataframe with precisely the records I want to drop, but if I do a

```
sales.drop(sales.CustomerID.isin(badcu))
```

It returns a dataframe with the first row dropped (which is a legitimate order), and the rest of the rows intact (it doesn't delete the bad ones), I think I know why this happens, but I still don't know how to drop the incorrect customer id rows.

Comment: you should drop by indexes

Comment: Use sales[~sales.CustomerID.isin(badcu)]

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You need

```
new_df = sales[~sales.CustomerID.isin(badcu)]
```

Comment: I use your method to exclude rows based on iphone numbers of my dataframe, it doesn't work. weird.

Comment: The error is as follows: TypeError: isin() takes 2 positional arguments but 69 were given

Comment: @ahbon, did you pass a list of arguments?

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `query`

```
sales.query('CustomerID not in @badcu')
```

Comment: I use also this method to exclude rows based on iphone numbers of my dataframe, it doesn't work. weird.

Comment: @ahbon may be a bit late on the comment but *how* did it not work? What error did you get? Different result?

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way is to drop by index,try it and let me know

```
sales.drop(sales[sales.CustomerId.isin(badcu)].index.tolist())
```